# iOS app tweaked for server connection

Tags: php, ios, xcode, server, lamp

I'm currently developing an iOS app and have reached the point where I need to implement a server back-end in order to support the core functionality.The app is built in a way to store certain questions locally (Within the app) and pose the questions to the app user. I need to tweak it such that it retrieves the question from a remote server. Furthermore, the question will reside in a specific folder within the remote DB. So the app will have to fetch the questions from the appropriate folder based on user login.

I have zero server experience and am need of some advise as to where I should begin with this. I would like to know if there is a template spec for this kind of task. With a template spec, I can hire a programmer and talk intelligently. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of BAAS (Backend as a service) provider, like Parse or Firebase. You might want to have a look into them. (Although Parse is going to shut down.)

Another simple way is to look into PHP Laravel.

Laravel is a great Framework which makes it really easy to set up a backend.
Have a look at [Laracast](https://laracasts.com)

Comment: I am looking to hire someone for this rather than learn and do myself. But I need to put it on paper first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a number of solutions:
**1)** You can use other services that provide backend functionality with REST API (as @Niklas Hein mentioned), it calls BAAS - backend as a service, such as Parse (but Parse is closing his service in one year), BaasBox, etc.
**2)** You can use [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/). This is service created by Apple, where you can store app data in the cloud, with authorization, requests, admin panel, etc.
**3)** Create you own back end. Here is a large number of languages and web frameworks, so php is not the only one solution. Ruby on Rails, Python Django, NodeJS, and many others on your choice.